# Getting the greatest value for a field for all records

Tags: netsuite

For our Employee records within NetSuite, we have a custom field called "Employee Number" with an ID of `custentity1`. I've created a workflow that will automatically create a new employee record and populate various fields but the one I'm having difficulty with is the Employee Number field. All I want to do is to grab the largest employee number there is out of all of the Employee records and add one to it for the new employee record.

The Employee Number field is a free-form text field so I know I'll have to use `TO_NUMBER`, but anytime I try and reference `{custentity1}` I keep getting an error saying that field is not found.

UPDATE: I've created a new custom field for our employee records called "Employee No." with an ID of custentity_employeenumber. I've also created a javascript file with the following:

```
function getMaxEmployeeNumber(){
   var empNumber = nlobjSearchColumn('custentity_employeenumber', null, 'max');
   return empNumber;
}
```

But how to do I get this to work with my records?

Answer (score 1):

NetSuite does have an auto-numbering mechanism built in to its native functionality that most of our customers use for this exact purpose. Is there a special reason this functionality is not being leveraged? This functionality is accessible at *Setup* > *Company* > *Auto-generated Numbers*.

I do not work much with workflows, so I do not know if this same functionality is possible there, but here is how I would solve this in SuiteScript:

1. Create User Event script that is executed on Before Submit Create event for Customer records
2. Create a Customer search that has a Search Column for `custentity1` with a summary type of `max`

   `new nlobjSearchColumn('custentity1', null, 'max');`
3. Running this search should give you 1 result, which is the maximum customer number. You can then just add 1 to it.

You could create a similar Saved Search in the UI to see what the result set looks like.

This will only really work if the field is a Number, not Text. I would suggest changing the field to an Integer field if you know that it will always be a number. This may clear out existing data, so first you could export all customers and their number to Excel and then do a CSV import after changing the field.

Comment: I like your approach...and unfortunately we did create the field as a free-form text (why we did this I have no idea) - I'll have to weigh out if exporting/importing users is the right thing to do or simply create a new field that's setup right.

Comment: Decision made: going to create a new field that is the proper integer number type field, copy the employee numbers over to this new field and use your post to see about doing what I need.

Comment: Well...I have no idea of how to get it all to work. I've created a javascript file with the following:

Answer (score 0):

How are you looking for the last employee in a workflow?

I know this can be done in js:

- Search employees - returns max 1000
- For number of employees give me the custentity1 of the last one - nlapiLookupfield('employee',employees[employees.length],'custentity1')
- Add +1 and save on new record

Answer (score 0):

If you use this search column

nlobjSearchColumn('custentity1', null, 'max');

You can also sort it in decreasing value so that the first result is always the max.  Something like

nlobjSearchColumn('custentity1', null, 'max').setSort(true);